# Option “Automatically reconanect to any nearby Mac or iPad” cannot be turned on

Tags: macos, universal-control

On Universal Control settings on my Mac, the option named “Automatically reconnect to any nearby Mac or iPad” cannot be turned on.  Even if I click the checkbox, it's immediately turned off again.  What's wrong with my Mac?

See also: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHi1V.jpg.